# R: the best way to locate the index of last observation of unique values of a column

Tags: r, zoo

I have the following data. It is always going to be in ascending order. I want to be able to locate the last values of all the unique values, i.e. the last value of `0, 1, 2, 3, 4 .....` In example below, `1` doesn't exist , so can skip and move on to find the last value `2` and return the **index**.

I want the a vector of indices of all the last observations of different unique values.

How can I do that ? Thanks.

```
    structure(c(0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 3, 3, 13, 14, 14, 14, 14, 24, 34, 
35, 37, 38, 38, 40, 42, 42, 43, 43, 44, 54, 54, 54, 64), index = structure(c(1167667200, 
1167753600, 1167840000, 1167926400, 1168012800, 1168099200, 1168185600, 
1168272000, 1168358400, 1168444800, 1168531200, 1168617600, 1168704000, 
1168790400, 1168876800, 1168963200, 1169049600, 1169136000, 1169222400, 
1169308800, 1169395200, 1169481600, 1169568000, 1169654400, 1169740800, 
1169827200, 1169913600, 1.17e+09, 1170086400), tzone = "", tclass = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), class = c("xts", "zoo"), .Dim = c(29L, 1L), .Dimnames = list(
    NULL, "testing"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(zoo)
df <- as.data.frame(df)
cumsum(rle(df$testing)$lengths)
# [1]  4  6  8  9 13 14 15 16 17 19 20 22 24 25 28 29
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `rle` function to determine the run lengths of each value, then index into the appropriate row by means of `cumsum`:

```
indices <- cumsum(rle(as.vector(a))$lengths)
a[indices]
                    testing
2007-01-04 16:00:00       0
2007-01-06 16:00:00       2
2007-01-08 16:00:00       3
2007-01-09 16:00:00      13
2007-01-13 16:00:00      14
2007-01-14 16:00:00      24
2007-01-15 16:00:00      34
2007-01-16 16:00:00      35
2007-01-17 16:00:00      37
2007-01-19 16:00:00      38
2007-01-20 16:00:00      40
2007-01-22 16:00:00      42
2007-01-24 16:00:00      43
2007-01-25 16:00:00      44
2007-01-28 16:00:00      54
2007-01-29 16:00:00      64
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
which(rev(!duplicated(rev(df$testing))))
#> [1]  4  6  8  9 13 14 15 16 17 19 20 22 24 25 28 29
```

Comment: Can skip the `rev()`s with : `which(!duplicated(df$testing, fromLast = TRUE))`

Comment: @sindri_baldur I know, but it's more characters to type!

Comment: So we are playing code golf now? `which(!duplicated(df,f=T))`  :)

Comment: @sindri_baldur now you're talking! I do like that better than `cumsum(rle`

Answer (score 0):

**1)** If `x` is the input xts object then this gives the indices of the last occurrence of each element.

```
findInterval(unique(x), x)
## [1]  4  6  8  9 13 14 15 16 17 19 20 22 24 25 28 29
```

**2)** This alternative gives a named vector as the result:

```
cumsum(table(x))
##  0  2  3 13 14 24 34 35 37 38 40 42 43 44 54 64 
##  4  6  8  9 13 14 15 16 17 19 20 22 24 25 28 29
```